# Java parsing csv and creating objects

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I am getting a "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" - which I believe basically means that the object is not getting created. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void loadData() {
    String csvFile = "/data/patientList.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br.readLine();
        String line1 = null;
        while ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] patient = line1.split(",");
            int bedNum = Integer.parseInt(patient[0]);
            Patient patient1 = new Patient(bedNum, patient[1], patient[2], patient[3], patient[4],
                    RESPIRATORY_RATE, HEART_RATE, SYSTOLIC, SPO2);
```

throws errors here, for example:

```
patientNameField.setText(Patient.getFistName());
```

Comment: Which line has the error? The error in question means that you are calling a member function from within a static function (there's no "this" available). But I can't tell from the code you've posted where the problem is. Not enough information.

Comment: I get the error wherever i try to use the Patient class objects. What information would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error sounds like your trying this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    loadData();
}

public void loadData() { /* method code */ }
```

This doesn't work, because the method `loadData` is not static and needs an object to be called on.

Change your code as follows:

```
public class MyClass { // you can name your class like you want
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final MyClass instance = new MyClass(); //assuming there is a non-argument constructor
        instance.loadData(); // call "loadData" on a specifc instance of MyClass
    }

    public void loadData() { /* method code */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ... I had a little play around and i now have this 

PatientJFrame instance = null;

        try {
            instance = new PatientJFrame();
        } 
catch (IOException ex) {
            
Logger.getLogger(PatientJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        instance.loadData();

I am still getting the error when ever i try to use the Patient objects though.

Comment: @ClaaziX You're getting the exact same error message? Or a different one?

Comment: it's the same error message wherever i try and get an object variable from the patient class - it's just not creating the objects...i think :/

Comment: @ClaaziX Then please update the source code in your question. Necessary information are: the line there the error occurs, the method in there that line is and the called method. The whole implementation of `loadData()` is not necessary if there is no error in there.

Comment: `Patient.getFistName()` ... what have you just learned :D? This won't work, as well, for the same reason as mentioned in my answer. Use the `Patient` instance of which you're trying to get the name. Maybe `patient1`? As a clarification why this is necessary: consider 5 different patients with own instances. Every instance contains the name of the patient it represents. How should Java know which name you want to get by calling `Patient.getFistName()`? That is why you have to call non-static methods on objects/instances to "tell" Java on which object the method should be performed.

Comment: Thanks Tom! :) I figured that something like that might be the case, i simplified it for the purposes of this question - i was actually trying to do a for loop, iterating over all the names to match a particular name and then display all the instances of that particular object....but it's time for bed!